# In CLojure how to call xml-> with arbitrary preds

Tags: clojure, xml-parsing

I want to create a function that allows me to pull contents from some feed, here's what I have... zf is from here

```
 (:require
        [clojure.zip :as z] 
        [clojure.data.zip.xml :only (attr text xml->)]
        [clojure.xml :as xml ]
        [clojure.contrib.zip-filter.xml :as zf]
        )

       (def data-url "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&keywords=music&location=Belgrade&date=Future")

     (defn zipp [data] (z/xml-zip data))

    (defn contents[cont & tags] 
      (assert (= (zf/xml-> (zipp(parsing cont)) (seq tags) text))))
```

but when I call it

```
(contents data-url :events :event :title)
```

I get an error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.ArraySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code? There are lots of things that doesn't make sense like assert form usage, what is zipp, what is text etc

Comment: I forgot to add zipp function from my code, and assert is from clojure/core - Evaluates expr and throws an exception if it does not evaluate to logical true.

Comment: oh, and text is from clojure contribs zip-filter [link] (https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/2ede388a9267d175bfaa7781ee9d57532eb4f20f/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/zip_filter/xml.clj#L57)

Comment: Your `=` form has only one value `(zf/xml-> (zipp(parsing cont)) (seq tags) text)` and no other value to compare to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Updated in response to the comments: see end of answer for ready-made function parameterized by the tags to match.)*

---

The following extracts the titles from the XML pointed at by the URL from the question text (tested at a Clojure 1.5.1 REPL with clojure.data.xml 0.0.7 and clojure.data.zip 0.1.1):

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip]
         '[clojure.data.xml :as xml]
         '[clojure.data.zip.xml :as xz]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(def data-url "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=4H4Vff4PdrTGp3vV&keywords=music&location=Belgrade&date=Future")
(def data (-> data-url io/reader xml/parse))
(def z (zip/xml-zip data))

(mapcat (comp :content zip/node)
        (xz/xml-> z
                  (xz/tag= :events)
                  (xz/tag= :event)
                  (xz/tag= :title)))

;; value of the above right now:
("Belgrade Early Music Festival, Gosta / Purcell: Dido & Aeneas"
 "Belgrade Early Music Festival, Gosta / Purcell: Dido & Aeneas"
 "Belgrade Early Music Festival, Gosta / Purcell: Dido & Aeneas"
 "VIII Early Music Festival, Belgrade 2013"
 "Kevlar Bikini"
 "U-Recken - Tree of Life Pre event"
 "Green Day"
 "Smallman - Vrane Kamene (Crows Of Stone)"
 "One Direction"
 "One Direction in Serbia")
```

Some comments:

1. The `clojure.contrib.*` namespaces are all deprecated. `xml->` now lives in `clojure.data.zip.xml`.
2. `xml->` accepts a zip loc and a bunch of "predicates"; in this context, however, the word "predicate" has an unusual meaning of a filtering function working on zip locs. See `clojure.data.zip.xml` source for several functions which return such predicates; for an example of use, see above.
3. If you want to define a list of predicates separately, you can do that too, then use `xml->` with `apply`:

   ```
   (def loc-preds [(xz/tag= :events) (xz/tag= :event) (xz/tag= :title)])
   (mapcat (comp :content zip/node) (apply xz/xml-> z loc-preds))
   ;; value returned as above
   ```

---

*Update:* Here's a function which takes the url and keywords naming tags as arguments and returns the content found at the tags:

```
(defn get-content-from-tags [url & tags]
  (mapcat (comp :content zip/node)
          (apply xz/xml->
                 (-> url io/reader xml/parse zip/xml-zip)
                 (for [t tags]
                   (xz/tag= t)))))
```

Calling it like so:

```
(get-content-from-tags data-url :events :event :title)
```

gives the same result as the `mapcat` form above.

Comment: Thank you Michal for your answer, I was trying out one more thing, to create preds, like this    (defn list-of-preds [& keys] (for [k keys] ['xz/tag '= k])). But when I use it in a fn I created with your answer defn get-contents-from-tag [url & tags] 
  (mapcat (comp :content zip/node)
        (xz/xml-> (zipp (parsing url)) (apply list-of-preds tags)))). I get this error java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0), do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to `apply` the `xml->` function to your list of predicates: `(apply xz/xml-> ... (apply list-of-preds ...))`. (You may want to consider having `list-of-preds` take a single collection argument rather than varargs and dropping the second `apply`; which version is better depends on how else `list-of-preds` is used.) Also, `['xz/tag '= k]` is a vector containing two symbols and whatever the value of `k` is. To create a `tag=` predicate, you need to call the `tag=` function: `(xz/tag= k)`. (NB. the equality sign is part of the name "tag="; you can't insert a space between it and "tag".)

Comment: Yes...I see, I fixed that now, but when I call the get-contents-from-tag I get an empty list, because list-of-preds isn't working correctly, perhaps I can make it a macro...

Comment: No need for a macro here, and anyway it would need to emit basically the same code you'd have to write for a working function. I've edited the answer to include a working function.

Comment: Thanks heaps Michal! I saw last night that macro wouldn't work, this is an excellant solution.

Comment: I just added one more thing that I find useful, so that a map of tag and its content can be creates    (defn map-tags-contents [url & tags]
 (map #(hash-map % (keyword (last tags)))
 (mapcat (comp :content z/node)
    (apply xz/xml->
     (-> url xml/parse z/xml-zip)
     (for [t tags]
    (zf/tag= t)
     ))))). So, when it's called, (map-tags-contents data-url :events :event :title), it gives a list of maps from the contents and tags.